# Xpath for regular text after bold text?

Tags: xpath

I am using xpath and I am trying to get the regular text from a this html that looks like this:

```
<p><strong>Gender: </strong>Female</p>
<p><strong>Years in Practice: </strong>30 Years</p>
<p><strong>Languages Spoken: </strong>English</p>
```

I tried getting the regular text with the xPath:

```
.//strong//text()
```

But I only get "bold texts" as result, not "regular text".
Female
30 Years
English
Not: Gender Years in Practice - Languge spoken

How do I get the regular text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get only the "regular" text, try:

```
//p/text()
```

If you need to make sure that the text returned is after `strong`, try:

```
//p/strong/following-sibling::text()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get just the regular text, use `//p/text()`